# Views Filter with Checkbox and Searchfield

Tags: views

I am searching for a solution to generate a custom filter consiting out of two fields. I want to have one Dropdown which holds the fields of my view, and then a second field "textfield" which will hold the search variable.
Here's an example. I do have a view with ID, name, email. My two filters would be a dropdown containing ID, name and email. And when I type something into the textfield, the field selected in the dropdown will be the filtered one. Does anyone know a module that does that? If not, I will write one.
I've checked Global combined filters so far, but they don't do what I want.
[image]

EDIT: just in case my question wasn't clear enough, this is what I want to achieve. And still got no idea how to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I've found so far is the Module [Composite Views Filter](https://www.drupal.org/project/composite_views_filter), which does quite the thing. You can display a filter on selection of dropdown. But not programatically. You have to fill your dropdown yourself.
Not quite what I was looking for, but better than nothing.